# Is there evidence Captain America would support torture for information?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, captain-america

Would the Captain America of the Marvel Cinematic Universe support torture or "enhanced interrogation" techniques for the purpose of gaining information?

Please support your case with quotes or explanatory scenes from the Marvel Cinematic Universe, or creative team quotes.

I'm **not** asking about fan opinion, popular opinion, or previous versions of Captain America from the comics.

Comment: I agree, given the second paragraph it's clear C. Ross isn't just looking for personal speculations, although it might be more clear if the title was changed to something like "Has Captain America ever expressed any opinions about torture as an interrogation technique?"

Comment: He is shown on many occasions in the comics to be against torture, though I don't have the time, nor the ability to post screenshots, to track them down right now. Vote to re-open.

Comment: Considering how he disliked the treatment that Bucky got in Captain America or the shadier part of Shield in the Avengers movie, yea, he probably wouldn't be down with waterboarding or other torturous interrogations. Not to add, that torture rarely gives valid intel.

Comment: On the other hand, he's perfectly fine with the idea of interrogating Sitwell by throwing him off a building...

Answer (score 17):

While it certainly doesn't seem to be his modus operandi, Steve Rogers seems to tolerate some degree of what we would consider "enhanced interrogation" techniques.

In [*The Winter Soldier*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1843866/) Steve Rogers allows Natasha Romanov to kick Sitwell off a roof with Falcon waiting to catch him and implies he's willing to let her do whatever is necessary to find out Hydra's true purpose.

[image]

> **Jasper Sitwell**: Is this little display meant to insinuate that you're gonna throw me off the roof? Because it's really not your style, Rogers.
>
> **Steve Rogers**: You're right. It's not. It's hers.
>
> *[Natasha throws Sitwell off the roof]*

<sub>Sourced from [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1843866/quotes?item=qt2221032)</sub>

Also in *The Winter Soldier* Steve has this conversation with Nick Fury regarding Operation Insight:

> **Nick Fury**: You know, I read those SSR files. "Greatest Generation"? *You guys did some nasty stuff.*
>
> **Steve Rogers**: *Yeah, we compromised. Sometimes in ways that made us not sleep so well.* But we did it so that people could be free. This isn't freedom. This is fear.
>
> **Nick Fury**: S.H.I.E.L.D. takes the world as it is, not as we'd like to be. And it's getting damn near past time for you get with that program, Cap.
>
> **Steve Rogers**: Don't hold your breath.

<sub>Emphasis mine, sourced from [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1843866/quotes?item=qt2040787)</sub>

Comment: Good answer, plus I love the gif. I would imagine Cap might knock a bad guy around a little, or try to scare him (as he did Sitwell), but that's the extent of it.

Answer (score 1):

In one of the recent comics series.  Cap is trying to get hydra out of shield.  He got one of the head guys all tired up and is ready to go to work on him.  But the bad guy says.  Cap would never tortured anyone for any reason.  Cap says you are right, nor would I allow it to happen in my presence.  Than he tell Nick to get the info and leaves the room!!

Comment: This is a great start of an answer.  Which series is it from?  A source would help a lot.